# Measure theory Rings and algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the intersection of any collection of rings (or algebras) of subsets of X is again a ring (or algebra) of subsets of X.

If we look at the ring case. I know that to prove a ring we have to show three thing
1) it contains the empty set
2) it contains the union
3)it contains the difference of sets

1)We are looking at the intersection of a collection of rings. Every set in every collection is a ring and so every collection contains the empty set and so the intersection contains the empty set

2) For property 2 we have to show that If A is the intersection of a collection of rings and B is the intersection of another collection of rings then $A \bigcup B$ is also an intersection of a collection of rings? Is this correct? And if so how do I state and prove it.

3)For property 3 we have to show that If A is the intersection of a collection of rings and B is also an intersection of another collection of rings then A-B is the intersection of a collection of rings? Is this correct? And if so how do I state and prove it.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Why did you change the original tags by the OP? They were perfectly reasonable, and in my opinion, much better suited than the current (abstract-algebra) tag

Comment: There is nothing about measure theory (or even measure algebras) here. The question is about basic properties of rings, that are studied in the context of abstract algebra. That the questions were found in a class on measure theory is irrelevant to their actual mathematical content. That they mention sets does not mean they have anything to do with set theory. The tags decide the visibility of a question. Irrelevant tags result on questions going unanswered.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: The question appears to be about rings in the [measure-theoretic sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets), *not* the [algebraic sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). As such it properly belongs in measure/set theory, not abstract algebra (I'm also not sure where you saw mention of a class on measure theory). I certainly agree that relevant tags are of high importance (which is why I'm making this point)

Comment: Yes, naturally these are rings of sets, in the Boolean algebraic sense.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: The operations of union and relative difference do form a ring, but not a Boolean ring. In any case, this assumes a level of abstraction that is unnecessary for this problem, which can be done using basic set theory. As the concept of a ring of sets is basic to measure theory, but not commonly encountered by pure algebraists, I still think the original tags were better suited, but I'm willing to drop the matter. Also, in the future please ping me when replying - I cannot predict if/when you will answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R_\lambda$ be rings $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda$

Let $C = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda$

i) $\emptyset \in R_\lambda \space \forall \lambda \in \Lambda$

$\implies \emptyset \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda$

$\therefore \emptyset \in C $

ii) let $A,B \in C$

$\implies A,B \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda$

$\implies A,B \in R_\lambda \space \forall \lambda \in \Lambda $

$\implies A \cup B \in R_\lambda \space \forall \lambda \in \Lambda $

$\implies A \cup B \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda$

$\implies A \cup B \in C$

iii) Let $A,B \in C$

$\implies A,B \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda$

$\implies A,B \in R_\lambda \space \forall \lambda \in \Lambda$

$\implies A-B \in R_\lambda \space \forall \lambda \in \Lambda$ (since they are rings/algebras)

$\implies A-B \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} R_\lambda = C$

$\therefore$ C is a ring, for algebra just show that the universal set X is in all rings.